# Getting sql error on deleting data from tables - target and source for delete

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to execute this query. it is to delete all the accounts that is less than the average of all the accounts in the `account` table. I am however getting this error:

`#1093 - Table 'account' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data`

The query is:

```
DELETE 
FROM account WHERE account_number IN 
(
  SELECT account_number FROM account 
WHERE balance < (SELECT AVG (balance) FROM account)
);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN`:

```
DELETE a
FROM account a JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(balance) as avg_balance
      FROM account
     ) ab
     ON a.balance < ab.avg_balance;
```

Comment: thank you. will tick it after 6 minutes.